# How to unlock iOS screen programmatically?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I'm currently exploring creating a jailbreak tweak. I want to unlock the phone screen. How is this done? What private API can be used to achieve this on iOS 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we are talking about jailbreak then you can write a SpringBoard tweak that does this (iOS 7 only)

```
[[objc_getClass("SBBacklightController") sharedInstance] turnOnScreenFullyWithBacklightSource:0];
[[objc_getClass("SBLockScreenManager") sharedInstance] unlockUIFromSource:0 withOptions:nil];
```

Without passcode lock the code will turn on the screen and unlock the device. With passcode it will turn on the screen and request passcode.

Comment: I'm in the middle of another task. I'll try this out soon and let you know.

Comment: Say, can this be used from a tool perspective and not a tweak?

Comment: No, it can only be used in SpringBoard tweak.

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I make a tweak that sets up a message port on SpringBoard that invokes the methods above. And the command line tool will just send a message to that port...

Comment: You could use Darwin notifications for that. Every application can send those, even inside sandbox. You don't need to create any ports or anything. `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter`, `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification` and `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` functions are everything you need.

Comment: @creker It is possible to write something simillar for iOS using external BIG frameworks (Like QT)? -I am new in iOS development

Answer (score 4):

I use Activator from Cydia to wake and unlock the device via SSH. It works on IOS 10.1.

```
activator send libactivator.system.homebutton
activator send libactivator.system.homebutton
```

lock command is here:

```
activator send libactivator.system.sleepbutton
```

Good Luck Have Fun :)

Answer (score 3):

My solution comes in two parts but it could be better:

1. Power on screen by simulating a power button press with this code:

   ```c
   VNCSendHIDEvent(IOHIDEventCreateKeyboardEvent(kCFAllocatorDefault, mach_absolute_time(),
   kHIDPage_Consumer, kHIDUsage_Csmr_Power, 1, 0)); // Power button down
   VNCSendHIDEvent(IOHIDEventCreateKeyboardEvent(kCFAllocatorDefault, mach_absolute_time(),
   kHIDPage_Consumer, kHIDUsage_Csmr_Power, 0, 0)); // Power button up
   ```
2. After 1, the screen will light up and then you can use [SimulateTouch](https://github.com/iolate/SimulateTouch/)'s stouch tool to simulate a swipe from the command line.

For 1 above, your code needs to have the `com.apple.private.hid.client.event-dispatch` [entitlement](http://www.saurik.com/id/8).

For more, you can also investigate how [Activator](https://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator/tree/master) performs the Unlock screen listener.

Comment: Is it possible to draw application's UI over entire screen in locked mode and substantially delay power save mode?

Comment: @avesus I'm not sure that can be done. Maybe you can ask that as a separate question here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a direct solution. 
You can use this tweak and library https://github.com/iolate/SimulateTouch to simulate a user swipe on the lockscreen to unlock the device.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't work on iOS 7 anymore. The underlying API GSEvent no longer works on iOS 7. I edited my question to clarify for iOS 7.

Comment: @radj The README on that project says it DOES support iOS 7.

Comment: @radj This tweak doesn't use GSEvent and it works fine on my iPhone4 running iOS7.

Comment: Gotta check again. Wait.

Comment: @cloudycliff How are you using it on your iPhone 4?

Comment: I install the tweak and library from cydia, and call [SimulateTouch simulateSwipeFromPoint:fromPoint toPoint:toPoint duration:duration] from my tweak. Don't forget to copy libsimulatetouch.dylib(you can compile it yourself) to theos's lib dir and add XXX-LDFLAGS = -lsimulatetouch in Makefile.

Comment: Also, this answer (assuming the swipe using ST works) lacks the part simulating a power/menu button so there is a working screen to swipe on.

Comment: @cloudycliff This is a bit more complicated but just adding here for additional info. I've been looking for SimulateTouch in Cydia on the 5c and it doesn't appear but it appears on the Cydia for iPod touch 4th gen. I installed it on the iPod and it works by calling `stouch swipe` via ssh. The problem is I still need to power on the screen.

Comment: My fault, I haven't thought about the power on part. Really have no idea how to power on the device programmatically. Maybe you can fake some events like notifications, messages, phone calls, alarm clock to wake the device?

Answer (score 1):

Call this code from the context of `SpringBoard` process.
For some case, you may use tweak for that.

*Note: ensure you're calling it from the Main thread*

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"SBBacklightController") sharedInstance] turnOnScreenFullyWithBacklightSource:0];
[[NSClassFromString(@"SBLockScreenManager") sharedInstance] unlockUIFromSource:0xD withOptions:nil];
```

Without passcode lock the code will turn on the screen and unlock the device.
With passcode it will turn on the screen and request passcode.